# Not able to detect the date column in a dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a dataframe with 3 columns which looks like

```
                   Addresses  Floor      Time
0   fd00::212:4b00:1957:ce5f  B2WL3  08:00:00
1   fd00::212:4b00:1957:ce4f  B2WL2  08:00:00
2   fd00::212:4b00:1957:d184  B2WL4  08:00:00
3   fd00::212:4b00:1957:d1ac  B2WL1  08:00:00
4   fd00::212:4b00:1957:ce21  B2EL4  08:00:00
5   fd00::212:4b00:1957:d186  B2WKK  08:00:00
6   fd00::212:4b00:1957:ce65  B2EL2  08:00:00
7   fd00::212:4b00:1957:e7d7   D3L2  07:30:00
8   fd00::212:4b00:1957:f02d   D3L0  07:30:00
9   fd00::212:4b00:1957:f01f   D2L1  07:30:00
```

i want to filter rows with time as 8 . When i do `df.dtypes` all the columns are of object type. I tried with

```
df[df['Time']=='08:00:00']
```

But this is returning a empty dataframe. I am not sure why this is happening ? Can someone help me with this?

Comment: I can't reproduce it. Can you try `df['Time'][0]`?

Comment: result is `datetime.time(8, 0)`

Comment: Gives an error -> `AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values`

Comment: I think you're comparing a time stamp with a string. Try the comparison with a pandas Series or numpy array of one element. I'm not at my machine now, can't confirm.

Comment: My bad. Try `df[df['Time'].apply(lambda x:x.hour) == 8]`?

Comment: `df['Time'].dtype` outputs an object but `type(df['Time'][0])` outputs `datetime.time`. any idea why ?

Comment: Also what is wrong in doing `df[df['Time']=='08:00:00']` ?

Answer (score 0):

There are empty or `nan` values in the time column.

Filtering with `df[df['Time']=='08:00:00']` should work.

I replaced one of the values in the sample dataset to an empty string and now the value of `dtypes`is object and filtering gives an empty dataframe

```py
>>> df
                  Addresses  Floor                 Time
0  fd00::212:4b00:1957:ce4f  B2WL2  2019-12-13 08:00:00
1  fd00::212:4b00:1957:d184  B2WL4  2019-12-13 08:00:00
2  fd00::212:4b00:1957:d1ac  B2WL1  2019-12-13 08:00:00
3  fd00::212:4b00:1957:ce21  B2EL4  2019-12-13 08:00:00
4  fd00::212:4b00:1957:d186  B2WKK
5  fd00::212:4b00:1957:ce65  B2EL2  2019-12-13 08:00:00
6  fd00::212:4b00:1957:e7d7   D3L2  2019-12-13 07:30:00
7  fd00::212:4b00:1957:f02d   D3L0  2019-12-13 07:30:00
8  fd00::212:4b00:1957:f01f   D2L1  2019-12-13 07:30:00
```

```py
>>> df.dtypes
Addresses    object
Floor        object
Time         object
dtype: object
>>> df[df.Time == '08:00:00']
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Addresses, Floor, Time]
Index: []
```

So I would suggest remove the empty cells and try again

```py
>>> df.Time = pd.to_datetime(df.Time.replace('', np.nan))
>>> df.dtypes
Addresses            object
Floor                object
Time         datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
>>> df[df.Time == '08:00:00']
                  Addresses  Floor                Time
0  fd00::212:4b00:1957:ce4f  B2WL2 2019-12-13 08:00:00
1  fd00::212:4b00:1957:d184  B2WL4 2019-12-13 08:00:00
2  fd00::212:4b00:1957:d1ac  B2WL1 2019-12-13 08:00:00
3  fd00::212:4b00:1957:ce21  B2EL4 2019-12-13 08:00:00
5  fd00::212:4b00:1957:ce65  B2EL2 2019-12-13 08:00:00
```

Comment: I am sure there are no null values in the dataframe. I even checked with `df.isnull().sum()`

Comment: might not be null, but empty string.